# Symfony2 Entity with description

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have Lector entity mapped by Doctrine to database. The code looks like this:

```
  class Lector {
  /**
   * @ORM\Id()
   * @ORM\Column(name="id",type="integer")
   * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
   */  
  protected $id;

  /** @ORM\Column(name="code",type="string",length=100,unique=true) */
  protected $code;

  /** @ORM\Column(type="string",length=100,nullable=true) */
  protected $firstTitle;

  ....
  }
```

I have used built-in CRUD generator in Symfony to create code for these actions.
However this generator uses column names as field description in generated pages like this:

```
 code <textbox>
 firstTitle <textbox>
```

I tried to make these fields more human readable by extending anntoation with

> options={"comment" = "Lector's internal code"}

but this did not work.

Is in Symfony 2 some way how to make description to every column which will be shown in project (everywhere where are column names rendered)?

*It is possible to edit view file and for every column make description I want. But this not what I want*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as I remember:

```
{{ form_row( form.email, { 'label': 'E-Mail:' } ) }}
```

or

```
{{ form_label(form.task, 'Task Description') }}
```

And symfony2 hasn't any solution for assign caption for field before render.
Also you can to use form classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can also set the labels in the form type generated by symfony2.

```
$builder
    ->add('comment', 'text', array(
        'label'  => 'Lector\'s internal code',
    ))
;
```